# Website session error ignoring session_start() when only one session_start is in the code

Tags: php, session

I have been using this login script on multiple websites on different servers, 
this is the first time I get this type of error. I have looked through many web pages trying to solve the issue but anything I try so far didn't solved the problem. I tried to destroy and use new `session_id` or to regenerate the `session_id` had no effect, as far as I can tell this error 
makes it impossible for me to manipulate sessions.

Also this code seemed to be working before but suddenly stopped working, and have been trying to fix it ever since. I tested this code on other web servers but they seem to be running fine only on the server where my website is hosted doesn't seem to be working.

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in 
/home/{website}/public_html/{website}/login.php on line 41.
```

Any help from veterans would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  // Error Reporting script
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  //database script
  $mysqli = @mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database');
  if (!$mysqli) {
      die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])){
      $errors = array();
      //Basic validation
      if(empty($_POST['customer_email'])){
          $errors[] = "Please enter your email";
      }else{
          $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['customer_email']);
          $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
          $email = strip_tags($email);
      }

      if(empty($_POST['customer_pass'])){
          $errors[] = "Please enter your password";
      }else{
          $password = trim($_POST['customer_pass']);
          $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
          $password = strip_tags($password);
      }

      //Setting up session
      if (empty($errors)) {
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM joinunion WHERE email = '$email'";
          $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
          if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
              $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
              if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
                 // start up session
                 session_id("User-Login");
                 if(!isset($_SESSION['email']['id'])) 
                 { 
                    session_start();         //<======THIS IS WHERE THE 
                                                    //ERROR IS ' LINE 41'
                 } 
                 $_SESSION['email']['id'] = $row['id'];
                 session_write_close();
                 // direct user to a new page - for testing purposes
                 //header("Location:index.html");
              }else{
                 $errors[] = "The username or password do not match";
              }
          }else{
              $errors[] = "The username or password do not match";
       }
    }
  }?>
```

Any help from veterans would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the error into the body text.

Comment: Did you try to use `session_start()` after `ob_start()`

Comment: You've said a lot… just not what exactly the error is.

Comment: @SaadSuri Yes I have done that still gave me the same error.

Comment: @deceze Apologise about that, I have just edited the question.

Comment: @Heikki I have just edited the question. Could you please check again?

Comment: I don’t know about this particular error, but setting a `session_id` to a fixed string which is shared among all users surely is nonsense. This means all your visitors share the same session with the same id!

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your reply. Could the problem be with the server, the code work on other servers I have tested out but not the one my website is in.